# Uniting two queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I want to preface this by saying I've tried several different methods using JOIN, where clauses, and UNION, and I'm not able to figure out what is going wrong, as these queries take too long to execute. I have two relatively simple queries that I want to combine into a single query.

First query:

```
select count(distinct id) as hits, name, weapon 
from damage 
group by name, weapon 
order by name, weapon desc;
```

Second query:

```
select count(distinct id) as shots, name, weapon 
from attack 
where category='Weapon' 
group by name, weapon 
order by name, weapon desc;
```

Both queries produce a table of results with a few hundred rows. I'd like to have an output table that shows shots, hits, name and weapon where the two intersect. The problem is that every way that I've been doing it hits my server's timeout of 30s, whereas the individual queries take a fraction of a second to complete, so I'm at a loss as to what I'm actually doing wrong.

Thanks for any help that can be given - mysql is a hobby to me, so I appreciate any experts taking their time to help me learn.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Incidentally, while I have no hard data, my instinct is that the vast majority of contributors under this tag are hobbyists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION` in a subquery, then group them in the main query. In the union, you use dummy values for the column that comes from the other table.

```
SELECT name, weapon, MAX(hits) AS hits, MAX(shots) AS shots
FROM (
    select count(distinct id) as hits, 0 AS shots, name, weapon from damage group by name, weapon
    UNION ALL
    select 0 AS hits, count(distinct id) as shots, name, weapon from attack where category='Weapon' group by name, weapon
) AS x
GROUP BY name, weapon
ORDER BY name, weapon DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would have never thought to do it this way. The query is fast, but returns '0's in the shots column. I will play around with it a bit and see if I can get it to return the correct numbers there, unless you see an obvious fix.

Comment: Replace 0 in the first line by MAX(shots) ?

Comment: Yeah, I got mixed up between the SELECT list in the main query and subquery.

Comment: You both rock. The MAX(shots) edit did the trick. Thank you so much for the help!